# AWS API Gateway: How to aggregate results?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am investigating AWS API Gateway and I keep seeing that you can use it to "aggregate the results from multiple old-school RPC-style web service calls into a single response".

However, I cannot find anything on how to achieve this.

I have looked through the Method Execution options but only see how to define a single endpoint URL.

Is aggregation only possible using a lambda function or is there a way to configure data aggregation within API Gateway?

Comment: Where are you seeing that? Could you link to documentation or blogs that say that you can do so?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - I first read it in the [Amazon API Gateway – Build and Run Scalable Application Backends](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-api-gateway-build-and-run-scalable-application-backends/)

Comment: I found this question when Googling for guidance on how to implement a BFF (backend-for-frontend, https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) using AWS API Gateway. I am trying to ensure I don't end up having clients call multiple microservices directly. Disappointed not to find an answer :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [Amazon API Gateway – Build and Run Scalable Application Backends](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-api-gateway-build-and-run-scalable-application-backends/)

This type of aggregation is possible, but you would need to implement it, according to your requirements.  It is not a feature of the service per se, but the service allows you to implement that, if you desire.

The point that they are making is that with a new single API call *that you implement*, you could then aggregate the results from multiple old-school RPC-style web service calls into a single response.

The implementation is up to you.

Comment: Yes, that is where I initially read it, although your link does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: I have updated the link. Does the answer make sense for you?

Comment: @RodrigoM please clarify what you mean by "implement it". What options do I have for implementing it?

Comment: I would start with a Lambda function. When invoked It would call two or more third-party APIs aggregate those results and return a single result